# How to fix weird success and error icon in SweetAlert2?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sweetalert2

So in January the SweetAlert2 is 100% normal. No bugs on the success and errors icon. but after February, the icons look weird and the animation is so bad.

I've tried to update the CDN because 2 days ago SweetAlert2 update. but still the problems not fixed. maybe you can help me.

---

This the image:

[Success icon error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRvBb.png)

[Error icon error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36jrO.png)

This is the code. I'm using flashdata to show the alert.

```html
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success-reg')): ?>
<script>
Swal.fire({
    icon: 'success',
    title: 'Kamu berhasil daftar!',
    text: 'Silahkan Cek Email Kamu, Buat Verifikasi!',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 2500
})
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Have checked in different browser or in incognito mode?

Comment: Have you introduced any new Fonts or CSS libraries into the site? That looks a lot like a font/CSS collision

Comment: @Rohit.007 i've tried in incognito and mozzila but still error.

Comment: @WesleySmith im using bootstrap and poppins font.

Comment: I guess there would be a chance of font/CSS or any new plugin collision - also marked by @WesleySmith

Comment: You can try creating a new small code and check whether it creates same problem on it too. So it will conclude the problem of Swal.fire or not

Comment: Do some basic debugging … start by looking what formatting and what font is actually applied, using your browser dev tools.

Comment: I have checked the Swal.fire plugin and it is not creating problem on a dummy app. So it mean there would be something wrong in you code. Try if you can share here or do the basic debugging

Comment: okay guys! i will do all of your advice!

Comment: ah man. im soooo tired.. the errors keep happening

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here: it happens because the font-size attribute of `<span>` in the rest of the document.
In my case to solve this issue I forced to change the font-size to 16px to specific class elements which "create" the success and error icons.

- For success icon:

```
.swal2-success-line-tip, .swal2-success-line-long {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

- For error icon:

```
.swal2-x-mark-line-right, .swal2-x-mark-line-left {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

It may not be the most elegant solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the fonts/font styling you are using in `html or body` tags especially if you are applying for `<p> <a> <span>` tags globally this happens.

Try to add the font styles in child elements of `body` tag or highest parent element other than `body` or `html`.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to [**`v9.x`**](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v9.0.0) of SweetAlert2. The animation looks good to me.

```js
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'Kamu berhasil daftar!',
  text: 'Silahkan Cek Email Kamu, Buat Verifikasi!',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 2500
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```