# Sweetalert 2 Issue on Icon

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, sweetalert

Anyone can help me?
I tried to used sweetalert2 on my app, but if used "question", "warning", and "info" it isn't correct.
Source from : https://sweetalert2.github.io/

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXB8t.png)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>

<script>
    function deleteConfirmation(id) {
        var urlsite = "https://"+window.location.hostname+'/gudang/public/blok/d/'+id;
        
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Peringatan',
            text: "Anda yakin ingin menghapus data?",
            icon: "question",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ya, Hapus!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                // redirect to delete data
                location.replace(urlsite);
                // notification
                Swal.fire(
                    'Sukses!',
                    'Data Anda berhasil dihapus, mohon tunggu hingga proses selesai!',
                    'success'
                )
            } else {
                // cancel to deleting data
                Swal.fire(
                    'Batal Hapus!',
                    'Data Anda batal dihapus!',
                    'error'
                )
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please add code not image

Comment: Ok, I've added it

Comment: I have same problem here, [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74245848/7072373).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Sweetalert the property that sets the icon can be called either 'icon' or 'type', try both. Can't do much more without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

try with options

```js
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Batal Hapus',
    text: 'Data Anda batal dihapus!',
    icon: 'error',
})
```

as per doc https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: If i use "error icon" & "success icon" there is no problem.

this problem only in "info icon", "warning icon", and "question icon"

Comment: your image is showing your having trouble with error icon

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean, the icon becomes double in symbol alert

Comment: @KurniawanEkoYulianto check css then

Comment: Look at "i" symbol, it to be twice, in the normal sweetalert only one

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom class to hide one of the icons. Some icons have content in a `::before` pseudo-class which doubles up.

**Create a custom class**

```css
.no-before-icon::before {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**Apply it to all icons** - *doesn't effect success or error icons*

```js
Swal.fire({
     title: "No more double icons",
     icon: "info",
     customClass: {
        icon: "no-before-icon",
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only include the JS file and do not include the CSS file, goes perfect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).